# Saving to database via ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to save to my database using Ajax. I have this code but couldn't work out what is wrong. All help is appreciated.

VIEW:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_add_item" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Item</h3>
            </div> <!-- end of modal header -->
            <div class="modal-body form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" id="form_add_item" method="POST">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="item_name">Item Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input type="text" name="new_item" placeholder="Item Name" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div><!-- end of modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="save" onclick="add_new_item()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div><!-- end of modal footer -->
        </div><!-- end of modal content -->
    </div><!-- end of modal dialog -->
</div> <!-- end of modal -->

function add_new_item(){
        var url="<?php echo site_url('accounting/add_item')?>";
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            data:$('#form_add_item').serialize(),
            datatype:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
                // alert(data);return false;
                $('#modal_add_item').modal('hide');
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error: '+textStatus);
                // console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function add_item(){
        $date=new DateTime();

        $item_name=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('new_item'));
        $added_by=$this->session->userdata('username');
        $date_added=$date->format('Y-m-d');

        $data=array(
                'item_name'=>$item_name,
                'added_by'=>$added_by,
                'date_added'=>$date_added,
            );
        $result=$this->item_name->add_item($data);
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE));
    }
```

MODEL:

```
public function add_item($data){
        // $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

        $this->db->insert($this->table,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

When I use the

```
success:function(data){
                alert(data);return false;
                // $('#modal_add_item').modal('hide');
            }
```

I can actually get the data that I need in the alert box but somehow it is not saving to the database.

Comment: have you tried to check what post data has been sent to your controller?

Comment: I tried alerting the data on success on ajax ant it gives me this result... Array([item_name]=>sss [added_by]=>somename [date_added]=>2016-12-20). How do I print or echo the "$data" in the controller. I can't get it to work. I can only alert the data in the ajax method.

Comment: what is the output of `alert(eval(data).status)`.

Comment: are you getting value true on alerting? then no problem in ajax.

Comment: Is this what you mean success:function(data){
     alert(eval(data).status);
     $('#modal_add_item').modal('hide');
    },

Comment: That gives me an error like this .... VM2584:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Comment: try to print_r( $_POST), see what data that has been sent